# Not able to show the database data in Tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

From my Sqlite database got the two table data in one array,

this array shows like this,

```
  (
       (
             {
                Name = A;
                Date = "2012-03-13 00:00:00";
                InvoiceNo = 1;
                Zip = 58555;
                type = sale;
             },
             {
                Name = B;
                Date = "2012-03-13 00:00:00";
                InvoiceNo = 3;
                Zip = 58556;
                type = sale;
             }
       ),

       (
             {
                Name = C;
                Date = "2012-03-13 00:00:00";
                InvoiceNo = 10;
                Zip = 58556;
                type = Gift;
             },

             {
                 Name = D;
                 Date = "2012-03-13 00:00:00";
                 InvoiceNo = 6;
                 Zip = 58556;
                 type = Gift;
             }
       )
  )
```

On "**cellForRowAtIndexPath**" code

```
         UILabel *ItemData  = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,32,80,18)]; 
         ItemData.text =[[Query objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Name"];
         [ItemData setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0]];
         [cell.contentView addSubview:ItemData];
         [ItemData release];
```

I want to print that data in to Tableview so need pass the "ValueforKey",

But not able to handle it,It"s crash the app,

Please, Any one suggest me, How can i do that?

Comment: I have tried with take that data in Dictionary format, But not able get it..

Comment: are your data saved in NSDictionary? if yes, save the your NSDictionaries in NSArray, then display the data in cell. [[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"]

Comment: @Anki : Post your code of **cellForRowAtIndexPath**.

Comment: thanks,@Sunajledif I will check that and get back to you.

Comment: @Devang: Hi, check my editable code.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array, that contains arrays, that contains dictionaries, right?
So, you need to marge this arrays in one single array, after that your code:

```
[[MergedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Name"]
```

will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
NSMutableArray *array =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (id *obj_1 in Query) {
    for (id *obj_2 in obj_1) {
        [array addObject:obj_2];
    }
}

now in cellForRowAtIndexPath method 

IteamData.text=[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey@"Name" ];
```